# Loop, Execution Time, and Progress Bar

Tags: php

I'm doing database and site backup list, there's a lot of loop in this process, and sometimes it's longer than `max_execution_time`. At the moment, my temporary solution is using `set_time_limit(0)`. But this approach "freezes" the browser.

In several web apps (like Akeeba backup/Joomla), they provide a nice visualization (progress bar) so user knows that there are processes happening in the background

How can i create such visualization?

Comment: You can't do it with 1 script and single request. PHP sends data after it's done processing. That means you can't output chunk by chunk to browser. Sadly, this is a bit broad to answer so in lack of a better syntagm - not doable *easily*.

Comment: You can use APC module for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like apps like Akeeba Backup (joomla) is really depend on Ajax Request